# how to set status as offline when internet connection is lost in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner who is developing an android app and i have implemented an online or offline status change. But i dont know how to change the status to offline In the DB with php when the user loses internet connection. Does anyone have a working solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an algorithm for that.  Every user updates his or her check_in date in the db every 2 minutes if another user views a particular user's profile and his or her last check_in date was more than 2 minutes ago, then the online status of the user whose profile if being displayed changes to offline to all users and is modified in the db.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static boolean isServerAlive() {
    //get server live status
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    String server_url = Constant.cons_app_url;
    boolean is_server_alive = false;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(server_url);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Integer connection_code = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (connection_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) is_server_alive = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return is_server_alive;
}
```